# BitMinter - At what data rate communication happens between the BitMinter java client and the server?

Tags: network, gpu-mining, bandwidth, bitminter

Looking for how many KB or MB transferred each way every second or minute, whatever is appropriate.

I am using a Macbook Pro and using GPU mining.